# Why is firefox caching a http request with Cache-Control : no-cache for an older file?

Tags: firefox, caching, http-headers

I make a firefox request and get these http headers:

```
Last-Modifed : today, 12:01
Cache-Control : no-cache
```

Then another one :

```
Last-Modifed : today, 11:01
Cache-Control : no-cache
```

Firefox keeps the first version. Is that normal ? I said no-cache, even if the file appears to be older !!! What Cache-Control should i use to make it use the second one ?

Comment: Are you restarting firefox between?

Comment: No, i'm not restarting firefox.

Comment: Odd, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) implies this shouldn't happen, at least with really old copies of Firefox; However, [as of 2008](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441751), [this behaviour has been seen elsewhere](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/) due to a bug. It may be an obscure bug that you've uncovered...

Comment: Should I file a bug report ? This may be a feature ...